# How I can get values of array result?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm new and I work in php. I have a problem, I have this "array" result from php script (this array was extracted with php of a html page):

```
Array ( [0] => {"autostart": false,"controls": true,"flashplayer": "/jwplayer7/jwplayer.flash.swf","image": "I NEED THIS", ga: {}, "mute": false, "ph": 1, "preload": "none", "primary": "html", "repeat": false, "skin": { "name": "tube" }, "stagevideo": true, "stretching": "uniform", "visualplaylist": true, "width": "100%", "aspectratio": "16:9", "provider": 'http', "startparam": "start", tracks: [{"file":"I WANT THIS","kind":"thumbnails"}], "sources": [{"file":"I NEED THIS","label":"480p"},{"file":"I NEED THIS","label":"720p"},"I WANT THIS"] ,"logo": {"logoBar": "I NEED THIS", "target": "blank","link": ""},"displaydescription": false,"displaytitle": false , "abouttext": "RapTu Player", "aboutlink": "" } )
```

I only need the values from `image:`, `sources:[{"file";}}` but I can't get the values, nothing, I try with javascript:

```
var str = '<?php echo $jw; ?>';
var json = JSON.parse(str);
var parse = $.parseJSON(file);
```

`$jw` is the variable of the array, and I don't have any result, nothing is printed. Could you help me? (Sorry for my english).

Upgrade: I resolved it using:

```
object = [<?php echo $jw; ?>]
for(f=0;f<object.length;f++){
}
```

Thanks everybody!

Comment: `$jw is the variable of the array` - and where is this variable assigned any value?

Comment: the value of `$jw` is `Array ( [0] => {"autostart": false....`

Comment: Is image the only value you need from that json?

Comment: Nevermind, I see now there is more `I need this` in the string

Comment: @Andreas Yes! I need the "Image", and "Files" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want doing that.
Then use

```
var json = '<?php echo json_encode($jw); ?>';
```

and in json variable you have json from array

or if you only sources you can use

```
var json = '<?php echo json_encode($jw[0]["sources"]); ?>';
```

but only work with first element in array $jw

Comment: I try with this code `<script type="text/javascript">

var str = '<?php echo json_encode($jw); ?>';
var json = JSON.parse(str);
var parse = $.parseJSON(autostart);

document.writeln("<br>autostart:"+json.image);

</script>` And I don't have results

Comment: @R.13 What about showing us, what actual code the PHP script produces? Would be much easier to tell you what is wrong. `var str = ???`

Comment: if you had in array 0 json you only $jw[0]

Comment: @smajl Hi! I have this in php: 

First: I get the content of html page - `$data = file_get_contents($url);`

Second: I find the script -  `preg_match_all("/<script(.*)>([^`]*?)<\/script>/",$data, $matches);`

Third: I get `$matches` - `$varmatch = $matches[1][8];`

Fourth: I get the content of `$matches` - `preg_match_all('#\((.*?)\)#', $varmatch, $vid);`

Fifth: I get new matches - `js = $vid[0][1];`

Sixth: Again I get content of `$vid` - `preg_match_all('#\((.*?)\)#', $js, $vars);`

Sevent: I have the array result - `$jw = $vars[1][0];` :)

Comment: preg_match_all returned array with index 0 on this case.
then use

    var str = '<?php echo $jw[0]; ?>';

Comment: @R.13 No, I mean the code produced by the PHP script - what's inside the HTML page. Just go to your browser and display the page source or inspect it in developer tools. There you will see `<script type="text/javascript"> var str = <the_final_product_of_php>;`. Are we clear?

Comment: @smajl Oh! Sorry, I inspect html and now I added the content to the question, please watch it

Comment: @Matx132 I tried with the second option and the result is: `Warning: Illegal string offset 'sources' ` What is bad? :(

Comment: @R.13 ok  use this code

This data in $jw is object in js, then only write to var and use as object :)
var object =  <?php echo $jw; ?>;

console.log(object.sources);

Comment: @Matx132 I resolved it using `for(f=0;f<object.length;f++){}` after  `var = object` Thanks a lot everybody! :)

Answer (score 0):

In php:- encode string in php properly

```
$json = json_encode('{"autostart": false,"controls": true,"flashplayer": "/jwplayer7/jwplayer.flash.swf","image": "I NEED THIS", ga: {}, "mute": false, "ph": 1, "preload": "none", "primary": "html", "repeat": false, "skin": { "name": "tube" }, "stagevideo": true, "stretching": "uniform", "visualplaylist": true, "width": "100%", "aspectratio": "16:9", "provider": "http", "startparam": "start", tracks: [{"file":"I WANT THIS","kind":"thumbnails"}], "sources": [{"file":"I NEED THIS","label":"480p"},{"file":"I NEED THIS","label":"720p"},"I WANT THIS"] ,"logo": {"logoBar": "I NEED THIS", "target": "blank","link": ""},"displaydescription": false,"displaytitle": false , "abouttext": "RapTu Player", "aboutlink": ""}');
$array1 = array($json);
```

Pass $array1 to html in script:-

```
var str = '<?php echo $jw; ?>'; // echo $array1[0] as $jw
var json = JSON.parse(str);    
var parse = $.parseJSON(file);
```

Comment: Hi! I tried like this: `$json = json_encode('$jw');
$array1 = array($json)`

And in javascript: `<script type="text/javascript">

var str = '<?php echo $jw; ?>';
var json = JSON.parse(str);
var parse = $.parseJSON(file);

document.write("<br>file:"+parse);

</script>`

And nothing happens, what I doing wrong?

Comment: @R.13 did you encoded your string in php properly? using json_encode() function

Comment: Yes, I think, I now I tried with: `$jw = $vars[1][0];` -> `$arr = array($jw);` -> `$jw1 = json_encode($arr);` -> `<script type="text/javascript">

var str = '<?php echo $jw1; ?>';
var json = JSON.parse(str);
var parse = $.parseJSON(autostart\);

document.write("<br>file:"+parse);

</script>` 

And I have the same problem, nothing happens, If I try with `var json '<?php echo json_encode($jw[0]["sources"]); ?>';` the result is: Warning: Illegal string offset 'sources', what is bad?